# Mirror a function about y axis

Tags: maple

I have a piecewise function from -1 to 0 in Maple, and I want somehow get a mirror piecewise function about y axis, just like here:

[image: Piecewice mirror example]

Is there any bult-in function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However, we can think about the code `reflect(p, [pt_2d, pt_2d])` in Maple, It is easy to do that as follows. I defined a function and their plots.

```
> with(plots):
  h := x->piecewise(x < -2, x+3, x <= 2, 5-x^2, 3-x):
  t:=x->h(-x):
  a:= plot(h(x), x = 0 .. 10, color = red, thickness = 3):
  b:= plot(t(x), x = -10 .. 0, color = green, thickness = 3):
  display(a,b);
```

[image]

Comment: Using the command `plottools:-reflect` might perform better than the approach of using `-x`, if say the original function were very expensive to compute (and if not computed by some procedure having `option remember`).

Comment: @acer: Thanks for the comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x$ with $-x$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: You beat me by 20 seconds! +1, my friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the substitution $ x \mapsto -x $. Note: functions such that $ f(-x) = f(x) $ are called **even**. For example, $f(x)=x^n$ is even if $n$ is even. Also, $ f(x) = \cos x $ is even.